# Git append the current commit hash to result of a commit command

Tags: git, git-alias

I want to append the hash of the ongoing commit to its result. I can retrieve the hash using this command:

```
git log --format=%H | tail -1
```

Then I try to merge a *commit* with command above and make an alias in '.gitconfig', like this:

```
[alias]
    ci = !git commit && git log --format=%H | tail -1
```

But this does not work; parameters of alias are send to *tail* command, not *git commit*.
How should I create this alias?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. Using the commit hash of previous commit as the current commit log?

Comment: No, just displaying the commit SHA1 hash in terminal; after the texual output of commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ci = !sh -c 'git commit "$@" && git log --format=%H | tail -1' --
```

You can find more info [here](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Advanced_aliases_with_arguments)

Also this is a more optimal way to get the hash of the last commit:

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:%H
```